# Checking if terminal is busy in VScode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I wanted to check if the terminals in vs code is busy or not.

```js
vscode.window.terminals.forEach((t) => {
  isBusy(t) // any way to determine
})
```

I checked through vscode api documentation but could-not find anything about this,